# An easy question about java and environment variables in ubuntu

Tags: java, variables, ubuntu, environment

I have Ubuntu 10.10 with java already installed. I am able to execute java command from any folder. I supposed that could be because I had java Classpath setted. But neither JAVA_HOME nor CLASSPATH are setted.

If I look at /etc/environment content I can see that PATH is setted to /usr/bin/ (among others). As '`which java`' returns /usr/bin/java, is that the reason why I can execute java from anywhere? If not, why is it?

Comment: This might be more appropriate for [Unix.StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute java because the command is on your path.

```
echo $PATH
```

will show you which directories are searched, in which order to find a particular program.  Since `/usr/bin` is on your path, when you type `java` it will eventually look at `/usr/bin/java`.  Note that in many systems this is a symbolic link (a file that points to another file) so `/usr/bin/java` often points to `/etc/alternatives/java` (which is also a symbolic link that points to the real executable).

Where the environmental variable `JAVA_HOME` comes into play is in tools and programs that check for `JAVA_HOME` and act on it instead of relying on the path.  In most modern Linux systems, the work done by the alternatives subsystem replaces the earlier (more problematic) `JAVA_HOME` technique.  That said, you might want to set `JAVA_HOME` anyway, should you encounter a tool that demands it.

One reason why `JAVA_HOME` is not as popular as it could be is that to access `JAVA_HOME` you need to run a shell, and not everyone wants to wrap every single Java item in a shell command.

Comment: @de3, yes, the answer is yes.  Sorry to forget the obvious answer in the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if java binary (or a link to it) is on a folder that is listed on the path then you can execute java without specifying the path to it (for example `/usr/local/java/latest/bin/java -jar x.jar`)
JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH have nothing to do with system path.
JAVA_HOME allow other software (or scripts) to know where to look for java installation.
CLASSPATH tells java where to look for classes (.class files resulting of compiling .java files).